# CustomValidator works with username = "test" and password="test", but nothing else

Tags: wcf

I am testing out the CustomUserNamePassword Validator for WCF and so far it only works if I validate the username test and the password test. If I use something else, such as test1 for the username and test1 for the password, it throws the FaultException.  Here is the code the validator:

```
public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
{
    if (userName != "test" || password != "test")
            throw new FaultException("Username and Password Failed");
}
```

I am using a Console App to connect to an IIS Hosted Service and I am calling instantiating the credentials like this:

```
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "test";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "test";
```

The above works, but if I hard code the validator to something like test1 and test1 and then do:

```
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "test1";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "test1";
```

The above fails even if I have:

```
public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
{
    if (userName != "test1" || password != "test1")
            throw new FaultException("Username and Password Failed");
}
```

I am building the app.config and the ProxyCode with svcutil. Could that have anything to do with it?  I did regenerate the code.

I figured out what the problem was.  I have 3 solutions (A WCF Service Library, A WCF Website that uses the service library, and a Console App that had code generated from the WCF Service Website url wsdl).  I was updating the WCF Service Library, and the Console app, but I was not updating the reference for the website.  Once I did this, it all worked fine.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Henk, I first had your same reaction, but I think I misunderstood the question. Xaisoft, you say that you update *both* the server Validate implementaiton *and* the client to change from "test" to "test1", right?

Comment: @carlos: I thought so but a) it should be said so more clearly, b) then it is a version/assembly mismatch that can be easily solved with a debugger but not from the info posted here.

Comment: @carlos, I will update my post.

Comment: @Henk, sorry for the confusion.  This is all new to me.

Comment: You're a member for 2 years with 400+ questions...

Comment: @Henk, I didn't mean stackoverflow is new to me. I meant WCF.  Also, regarding attaching the debugger, I did that and I was getting a FaultException with an inner exception of Username and Password Failed.  Once I updated the website reference, it worked.

Comment: @Henk, also look at our comparison, I have 400+ questions and 40+ answers.  You have 2300+ answers and 20+ questions. Obviously, we are opposite in our experience. This should tell you something, that I am just a beginner.  If I am going to get blasted, I might as well not ask anything.

Comment: Just look back at (the 1st version) of your question and pretend you want to answer it. Not much to go on, is there?

Comment: @Henk,  all I did was add the Validate method implementation. I guess I assumed wrong when this when I thought it was understood that I would change the hard-coded values.  Goodbye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[updated answer, I had misunderstood the question]

Is the server side being redeployed? You can try updating the application, or trying to attach a debugger to the server side to see if you have the correct code being run.

Comment: Carlos, I am regenerating the proxycode using svcutil.  I will try your suggestion of attaching the debugger.

Comment: thank you for your patience and sorry for the confusion.  I figured it out because of your help. I will update my post to tell you what the problem was.